# DeviseMailer#reset_password_instructions Outbound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

While in press forgort password in devise temple getting executed by i'm getting out of bound mail like below.

```
 Rendering devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
 Rendered devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb (0.7ms)
 DeviseMailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 14.8ms
```

but mailer template is getting rendered in my console.

```
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Hello arun.yinyan@gmail.com!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=92RT59FWsw_duH1Y5kbg">Change my password</a></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

Completed 302 Found in 1930ms (ActiveRecord: 103.3ms)

Comment: What's the problem? This seems to be working exactly as it should be?

Comment: [**Outbound**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/outbound) is not the same thing as ["Out of bounds"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/out-of-bounds). Were you just confused by this use of language?

Comment: Hi, Tom .!  I doesnt got any mail in my Gmail inbox. i dont know why it is? This is what the confusion be.  i had also configured smtp_settings properly.    "Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in 14.8ms"

Comment: *"processed outbound mail"* means **it worked**. Maybe the email is getting stuck somewhere else - e.g. by your firewall, junk mail folder, or a mail interceptor like `letter_opener`, `mailtrap` or an `Action Mailer Interceptor`?

Comment: thanks Mr Tom Lord. My mail has security level high, i had reduced the security level now its working fine